# This video contains audio but audio won't play, why?

Tags: audio, video, audio-recording

I have created [this video](https://easyupload.io/59n93r) using swift.

This video contains audio, but audio won't play.

You can extract the audio using FFMPEG

```
ffmpeg -i movie.mov audio.mp3
```

I have encoded this video using the following settings:

```
Video: MP4, H264
Audio: Apple Losseless, 2 channels, 32 bits, 44,100 Hz
```

There is no way t make this video play with audio.

I have tried other audio formats, like AAC. Same problem.

If I convert this video to another format using a software like Handbrake, audio will play.

This video is 60 FPS.

Can someone please analyze the video and see why technically the audio is not playing?

The audio is not playing on Quicktime my Mac running Catalina and also not playing on iPhone or iPad running iOS 13.5. Audio will play on macOS thru VLC.

Thank.

Comment: The video plays without audio on macOS Catalina using Quicktime and also on iPad and iPhone. The audio plays on the mac if I use the VLC player. The audio also plays on the mac with Quicktime if I recode the video using Handbrake. So, something is wrong with the encoding.